# Why has my answer been deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer, undelete-request

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow.

I've answered a question here [fastest way to set every pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673040/fastest-way-to-set-every-pixel)

Looks like question author found my answer helpful. I'm not trying to argue or anything, just to understand.

Comment: +1 For asking for a constructive review. At present only people with >10K reputation can see your deleted answer. If you quote it here you'll have a wider field of people to give feedback

Comment: Here's my answer:Maybe you should post some code?

Check the memory traversal if you use loops. You should traverse your buffer in the right order, otherwise you may have cache miss at each iteration. If you use nested loops sometimes you only have to switch the x/y iteration order.

Also, don't read data from graphic memory. It tends to be slow. Only write to PBO.

**Edit:** 

It looks like a syncro issue. I'm not sure you need to map pbo at every frame.  Check this link on http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html. There's also a workaround for stalls which could improve things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen worse answers.  I've undeleted this one.

Worth noting: You don't have to put **EDIT** in your posts.  Every post on Stack Overflow has a detailed edit history, which anyone can look at.  The edit history for your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18673478/revisions).

But *"maybe you should post some code"* definitely belongs in a comment, not in answers.  You should try to keep such content out of your answers, if you can.

Stack Overflow moderators are only presented with an excerpt of the answer in the moderator dashboard.  If "maybe you should post some code" is all they see (which suggests that your merely trying to communicate with someone, rather than answering the question), your answer is going to get deleted.

Comment: Great edits - I think that first line is what did him in, originally.

Comment: `Stack Overflow moderators are only presented with an excerpt of the answer in the moderator dashboard.` - they really need to get you guys better tools :)

Comment: ok, i understand this point. long is the road :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: I have suggested an interface similar to the Review Tools for handling flags, which would provide better visibility without having to open the post in a new window.

Comment: It is possible to expand the answer inline in the dashboard. Expanding it also shows the question for context.

Comment: @mmyers: It's clumsy, though.  It requires scrolling of the browser window and dragging down a bar to see the question.  I find the Review UI far more intuitive.

Comment: @mmyers I definitely need to start doing that more. A better interface would help, for sure. (noting this since I'm the one who deleted)

Answer (score 2):

It was deleted by a moderator after being flagged as "It should be a comment".

For users with >=10k reputation it is still [visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18673478/1983854). Comments show:

> That should be a comment. Based on his current question state it's
>   impossible to see what's the problem . – Michael IV Sep 7 at 12:54
>
> i've added some code – Schnizel1337 Sep 7 at 13:05
>
> got it, i changed the loop iteration order and now it works, thanks! –
>   Schnizel1337 Sep 7 at 13:55

I don't know if it should be undeleted, as it is not clear if it was useful to solve the question.

Comment: i don't know neither :) i've tried to assist op, one of the clues i've given has apparently helped him. well, that's not a big deal...

Comment: Comments aren't flags. Just because someone has commented on something being not an answer doesn't mean a flag is automatically generated.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I know, but in this context I guessed some user flagged it after commenting.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18673478/1488917) should not have been deleted.

The answer is not a good answer, but nonetheless attempts to provide inputs and suggestions as to what the problem may have been. It should have been downvoted at most, but not deleted.

Chances are that the first line in your answer prompted the deletion:

> Maybe you should post some code?

This should not be a part of answers, but added as comments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a reasonable, though not stellar answer.  Three people thought it was good enough to upvote, and it seems to contain useful information.

I don't think it should have been deleted.

Here's the full text of the answer:

> Maybe you should post some code?
>
> Check the memory traversal if you use loops. You should traverse your
>   buffer in the right order, otherwise you may have cache miss at each
>   iteration. If you use nested loops sometimes you only have to switch
>   the x/y iteration order.
>
> Also, don't read data from graphic memory. It tends to be slow. Only
>   write to PBO.
>
> Edit:
>
> It looks like a syncro issue. I'm not sure you need to map pbo at
>   every frame. Check this [link on OpenGL Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).
>   There's also a workaround for stalls which could improve things

Comment: It seems like a fine comment.  It contains requests for clarification, general advice not specifically answering the question, and a link to outside resources.  All good things to have in comments, but none of which constitutes an *answer*.

Comment: Based on OP's comment, *and checkmark*, this answer *did* in fact answer the question.

Comment: The post didn't answer the question, it gave the OP enough information for him to come up with an answer of his own, which is great, but is still a *comment*, not an *answer*.  The OP checking a checkbox doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1):

Going through each part of your answer:

> Maybe you should post some code?

This is a request for clarification.  This belongs as a comment, not an answer.  This isn't answering a question.

> Check the memory traversal if you use loops. You should traverse your buffer in the right order, otherwise you may have cache miss at each iteration. If you use nested loops sometimes you only have to switch the x/y iteration order.

This is mentioning something that the OP should look into.  Here it seems that you don't have enough information from the question itself to know if this is something that could be built into an answer or not, so you're providing some debugging tips for the OP to help him get to an answer.  Again, this would make a great comment, but it's not an answer to the question, it's leading to an answer but it itself isn't an answer.

> Also, don't read data from graphic memory. It tends to be slow. Only write to PBO.

This is just a general tip unrelated to the question.  It makes a good comment, and is something you could add to an answer if it also answers the question.  By itself though, this isn't an answer.

> **Edit:**

As Robert said in his answer, there's no need to include this.

> It looks like a syncro issue. I'm not sure you need to map pbo at every frame.  Check this link on [OpenGL Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html). There's also a workaround for stalls which could improve things

Here your not answering the question, you're linking to an external resource that *might* help the OP come to an answer.  On SO any links in an answer should be supplementary, not essential to the post answering the question.  If someone never follows any link in your post they should still get an answer.  Links should be either to cite works, or to provide additional information beyond the answer to the specific question.  If you quoted or summarized enough of the information from this link to answer the question, then this post could become an answer.

---

All in all, this post is *close* to being an acceptable answer, there's a nugget there that could be turned into one (which is likely why Robert decided to undelete it), but it's not there yet.

When you have requests for clarification, or just general ideas that require more information from the OP for them to be developed into a real answer, you should comment.  When the OP responds/edits with the requested information (as he did in this case) you can then turn these ideas into a post that truly *answers the question*.

With that, and incorporating enough of the content of anything you link to within the post itself, you could turn this into a good answer.

Comment: Troubleshooting steps and partial answers have always been acceptable post content on Stack Overflow (under the "get a quick answer to your question" theory).  They are still subject to upvoting and downvoting like any other answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've never seen it said that troubleshooting steps should be posted as answers.  They're virtually always posted as comments in my experiences.  As for a partial answer, sure, I can see those posted as answers, although I usually find them to be rather poor answers and I don't like seeing it, but I agree they shouldn't be deleted as non-answers.  This isn't a partial answer though.

Comment: But you'd agree with me that it is an answer and not spam, an attempt to communicate with another user, or saying "thanks."  Joel Spolsky has specifically stated (in places that I'm too lazy to look up right now) that troubleshooting steps and partial answers are OK, but see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd agree it's not spam, I *disagree* that it's not attempting to respond to another user/post, I agree it's not saying thanks.  I disagree that it is an answer, although I'd say it's close, and could *become* an answer with some modest editing.

Comment: Downvoting or editing answers like this is still preferable to deleting them.  Comments are meant for clarification, not action.  If some suggestion solved the OP's problem, it needs to be in an answer, not a transitory comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The link is in support of short, concise, expanded answers that *answer the question* but that don't go into detail, don't explain any more than they absolutely have to, etc.  That's different from a post that doesn't actually answer the question at all, even if it contains useful information.

Comment: Fair enough, but as a mod, I'd prefer to reserve the deletion hammer for content that truly doesn't belong there, like spam, @comments and "thanks."  I'm especially reluctant to delete accepted answers with a score of 3, like the one we're talking about here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem here is that, at the time the answer was posted, there was simply insufficient information to post an answer.  The information needed for an answer was only added after the answer was posted.  A clarifying comment was needed for this answerer to know both that his idea is on the right track, and for him to be able to assert it as an answer, not as some vague guess.  Once the clarifications were provided, an answer could be posted.  Ideally the question would also have been closed until it was clarified, to prevent such non-answers from being posted.

Comment: We can't always expect folks to do things in the "correct" order, @Serv.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, but at the very least I'd like to be able to make them aware of it when there is a problem.  The answerer should learn that it's important that clarifying questions be posted as comments, and that if they don't have enough information to really give a full answer they should wait for the clarifications (possibly even vote/flag to close) rather than trying to answer it.